# Tester able to install Sandboxed Mac App without UDID

Tags: xcode, macos, sandbox

I have created a sandboxed version of my Mac App. Now I've sent it out to testers. One tester though didn't have his UDID registered in the provisioning file that belonged to the app. Still, he was able to run the app.

Shouldn't that be impossible?

My signing is set to "Mac App Store" in Xcode 5.

My Code Sign for Release is set to "Mac Developer". I've haven't done anything in the dev portal, I've let Xcode handle all the certificates and prov. files.

When looking in the dev portal, I see that there isn't any provisioning profiles available under "Distribution". Do I need to make these manually?

For iOS I would've created a distribution provisioning profile for ad hoc distribution.

**Update**

I also tried to create my own provisioning profiles and App ID's to no avail.

Should the `GateKeeper` icon be visible under `Entitlements`?

[image]

I don't want any other computer than the ones I've added to the devices in the provisioning file, being able to run the app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that it is not possible having only devices in the device list being able to run the app.

Comment: If someone finds a way, I will gladly mark that answer as correct.

Answer (score 2):

> A store provisioning profile is a distribution provisioning profile
>   that authorizes your app to use certain technologies and services, and
>   ensures that your app is submitted by you. A store distribution
>   provisioning profile contains a single App ID that matches one or more
>   of your apps, and a distribution certificate.
>
> For iOS apps, you need a store provisioning profile to submit your
>   app. For Mac apps, if you use technologies and services that require
>   provisioning, you need a store provisioning profile. If you don’t use
>   these technologies and services, you can use the distribution
>   certificate to sign your app.

Mac OS X apps can be run without being code-signed, or needing to be required of having provisioning profiles (gatekeeper settings allow it, as well as many non - AppStore apps). OS X is not jailed like iOS, so it's quite different in that aspect. There are ways of codesigning your app that could make it not run under specific conditions, however, the provisioning mechanism for OS X is more to adhere to Apples policies, keeping things sandboxed properly, as well as ensure that an app released is genuinely by who it's claimed to be from.

Comment: But should it be possible to start the app on a computer that doesn't have the correct provisioning profile installed?

Comment: If your app's code signature only lists the sandbox entitlements, a provisioning profile is not required. Gatekeeper is happy provided that the signing identity is valid.

Comment: @retainCount The problem is that Gatekeeper is not happy. My testers have had to set "Allow apps downloaded from:" to "Anywhere". Second problem, I don't want anyone else besides my testers being able to launch the app. Is that possible?